# Which sentence is grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

Question..

Which sentence is grammatically correct below?

**It forces me to confront my issues as there are no visible clutter that is distracting me.**

or

**It forces me to confront my issues as there is no visible clutter that is distracting me.**

The only difference between the two sentences is the word **are** and **is**.

I'm not sure which one is right.. would really appreciate your help!!

Thank you!! =)

-L

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

The verb "is" matches the *number* of the object "clutter" and is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!! =)))